# Spark Streaming : how to get logs in spark master UI

Tags: logging, apache-spark

I have spark Job which I execute using Apache Zeppelin, I can see the `println` statements which executes in driver program on Zeppelin console. But the real pain point is, I am not getting the logs from the code which executes on spark executor.

In Spark master UI there is one link to see `stdout` logs, but its empty always.

What is the best way to log spark application? Or to be more precise how can I see logs on spark master UI in `stdout` link?

Comment: Are you supplying a custom logger?

Comment: I think I am not supplying any. @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov how to supply CustomLogger?